# Cariablevalue changed to new value which i never assigned

Tags: c#

How can current variable became 0 since i never assign new value to the current variable here

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        int current = 3;

        List<string> testing = new List<string>() {"Saya","Kamu","Dia"};

        for (int i = 0; i < testing.Count; i++)
        {
            if (current > 0)
            {
                string tst = testing[--current];
                Console.WriteLine(tst);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total" + current); /// it become 0

        for (int i = 0; i < testing.Count; i++)
        {
            if (current<testing.Count)
            {
                string tst = testing[current++];
                Console.WriteLine(tst);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output

> Dia
>
> Kamu
>
> Saya
>
> Total 0     // how can be 0 ?
>
> Saya
>
> Kamu
>
> Dia
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You have some misunderstanding of your code. Current is indeed assigned from the beginning. I think you meant the variable is never updated, but it clearly was through the '--' operator

Answer (score 2):

You are decrementing `current` here:

```
string tst = testing[--current];
```

The loop runs three times, so it becomes zero.

`--current` is equivalent to:

```
current = current - 1
```

Comment: Just adding a link to the `--` operator. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/decrement-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you are subtracting 1 from `current` in this line:

```
string tst = testing[--current];
```

And here although you had labeled it **Total**, you are printing out the `current` which has become 0:

`Console.WriteLine("Total" + current);`

Answer (score 0):

```
string tst = testing[--current];
```

Your issue is your "--current" that's a decrement. Much the same way i++ is an increment. After a few loops you're going to 0.